# Opera mini single column view css layout issues

Tags: responsive-design, breakpoints, opera-mini

I am new into responsive web design and but I have a problem with my first website when viewed using opera mini. I want to ask why is opera mini hiding content and changing my widths when single column view is on. is there something I can do to prevent this. I tried everything I know int web design and it's still the same unless there are tricks out there that I don't know of.

Comment: there are lots of html and css properties that not supported by opera mini see here http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/

Comment: so in this case you need some browsers hack like http://browserhacks.com/#om and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Answer (score 1):

Opera Mini in single column view is a special mode which as its name implies will transform CSS layouts in a single column layout and often break widths on purpose. Or as per [Opera](http://www.opera.com/blogs/mobile/2014/07/opera-mini-ios-activate-single-column-view/):

> Single column view transforms webpages to fit the screen width. This way, you don’t have to scroll left or right.

The UCMini proxy browser render similarly. I believe this is mainly for very small screens such as 240x360, and historically for feature phones, so that the content will fit in. I don't think it's worth worrying too much about esthetics in that context. If it hides elements. Maybe it's because they are outside of the media query breakpoint, or maybe are generated via js. It's hard to say without seeing.

One thing to keep in mind is that Opera Mini generally has a viewport width that is much smaller than the default device-width you'd normally expect. The viewport size also depends on Text size. So it's complicated. Say for 320px "normal" device-width with medium text size. The Opera Mini width will only be 300px by default.

So if you want to play well with Opera Mini you really have to plan between 240px and 360px widths. And per Opera [recommendations](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/):

> Putting things in a logical order is important because some browsers (Mini included) will sometimes collapse complex layouts so they are displayed on the screen in a single column

I have experienced a bug where a flexbox row in Single Column View will not collapse into a column as it should and flexbox layouts getting messed up.

Comment: hexalys, how did you fix the bug where a flexbox row in Opera Mini's Single Column View will not collapse into a column?

Comment: I did not. My target users doesn't justify worrying about this mode. If you want to address it. You can probably use the `media="handheld"` media query as described in [rendering modes](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/) by Opera.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed after hours of CSS tweaking. 
I just added to head `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="styles.css">` which is the same css file that the whole website uses. And Opera now works in single-column mode!